# Javascript is ignoring value of textbox

Tags: javascript

I have some issues with a calculation in Javascript.

I an filling a textbox with a value:

```
<script>
  function getTi() {
    $('#total_item').val('<?php echo $m; ?>');
    $('#total_item').trigger('change');
  }
</script>
```

In this case the value of `#total_item` = 3.

In the second part of my script a want to get the value of the textbox and add a `+ 1` to it:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var count = $('#total_item').val();

    $(document).on('click', '#add_row', function() {
      count++;
      $('#total_item').val(count);
      // more code
    };
  };
</script>
```

When I execute my script the script overwrites `3` with `1` and adds `+1` everytime then I click on #add_row.

I think there is something wrong with `var count = $('#total_item').val();`. The script works when I change `var count = $('#total_item').val();` to `var count = 3`.

Does someone know why my script is not working properly?

Comment: It seems like the second script is executed before the first one.

Comment: [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) returns a string. Convert it to a number.

Comment: Get the current value once click event occurs, not before. Also we have no idea where `getTi()` gets called or when. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: I assume your add_row function adds a row of some kind to a container of some kind.  Why not count the number of existing rows using `document.querySelectorAll('#container .your-row').length` or similar.

Comment: Click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55326438/edit) then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide relevant HTML and JS in a [mcve]

Comment: I have tried to convert total_item with: `var count = parseInt($('#total_item'));`. When I execute the script I get `NaN` in `total_item`